# How set session attribute during session creation?

Tags: java, session, servlets

It is needed to create session, do some action and save result in session, **before** session is exposed in other code parts. There is a [HttpSessionListenr](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) but it handles session created event after session is created. It seem there are no guaranties that session accessed between listener receive event. Is it true?

How to override session creation mechanism or execute code before session is created?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

1. Access the session using a helper method.
2. Create a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to initialize the session.

Option 1 means that your code *must* use the helper. The helper will initialize the session, if needed.

Option 2 means that the session will be initialized for all filtered requests, even if not needed.